# how to open / continue expo project in another device with github

Tags: react-native, github, expo

I'm pretty new to the expo and developing a mobile app, currently I'm using expo dan react native

I've built an app with the expo and I want to open it on another laptop, so I use GitHub to commit my work there

on the new laptop I already installed expo, node, vs, etc. i cloned the project and can't start it on my new laptop with "npm start"

it shows error like this
"Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed"

which I already checked on my cmd with expo --version

TL: DR  how do I start the expo on another laptop with GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed the issue, the console recommended me to do yarn add expo , i already did the yarn add expo before writing this question and it didnt fix me thats why i thought there is something i need to do other than doing that

so after exploring expo documentation and found nothing , i just tried to do yarn add expo BUT in my cmd , not in my console on vs code

it worked perfectly for me and the strange thing is , i cant debug expo in my phone with LAN connection, which now i have to use tunnel connection for this to work where in my old computer i use the LAN connection perfectly fine

TLDR : do yarn add expo in cmd not in vs code console

Answer (score 0):

Did you already clone your repo to your new machine?
If not you should download your code to your new laptop.
Next you will have to cd to the directory of your app in your terminal.
Afterwards you’ll have to run
`expo install`
And after this is done you can run the following command (still in your app folder)
`expo start`

Comment: thankyou for the answer ! i already cloned the projects and still got the problem , the problem is fixed though , sorry for the trobule :)

Comment: You’re welcome and no worries, I’m glad you found the answer!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with npm?